# Binary Tree applications - Storing dates

Tags: computer-science, theory, binary-tree

I'm working on a simple app and the specs mandate that a binary search tree must be used for storing dates in DD/MM/YYYY format. Question is, I'm having a hard time visualizing the structure and how nodes shall be organized.

Sorry for being vague, but can I get some pointers?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: By the way, chances are high that you'll want this to be a balanced Binary Search Tree.  Do you have any textbooks/reference books on Data Structures and Algorithms?  If so, look up Red-Black Trees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what is required is that you make a comparator function which determines if a date is earlier or later (or equal) respective to another. You'd use this function to determine where to place a new node and/or if it already exists in the tree. The rest would work like a regular binary tree holding, say, Integers.

For example, you can put earlier dates as left children and later dates as right children.

Comment: what would be the root node, then?

Comment: The root node would be whichever date you add first, the rest of the tree will branch out from there in relation to that date.